# Angular rails templates not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, angular-template

I use aws ec2 with elastic beanstalk(eb) to deploy application then I try to access application I got empty page and no error on console. I put my template under

> app/assets/templates/simple_template.html.erb
>   
>   Then I tried to check with server in rails log (production.log) nginx log (access.log , error.log) is no any error in these logs

I search on Google then I found some people talk about

> gem sprockets

then I put **gem 'sprockets', '~> 3.0'** to gem file is still not working

More Detail

[Empty page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugXrz.png) 
[Inspect HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqwpf.png)

Comment: Post your relevant code based on your setup?

Comment: Could you please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

[jdgray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4735914/jdgray) I tried many debug I just found and post it in here https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates/issues/155

Checkout this

```
use strict'

alert('route'); <----- is working

angular.module('core').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
// Redirect to 404 when route not found
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
  $injector.get('$state').transitionTo('not-found', null, {
    location: false
  });
});

alert('inside route') <--- is working
// Home state routing
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'players/layout/home.client.view.html',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  controller: 'MasterController',
  resolve: {
    user_noti: function($http, $stateParams,jwtHelper, $window) {
     alert('insde part') <--- not woking
      if($window.user) {
        return $http.get('/api/v1/notifications');
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    },
    user_unconfrim_ticket: function($http, $stateParams,jwtHelper, $window){
      if($window.user) {
        return $http.get('/api/v1/tickets/unconfrim');
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    }
  }
})
.state('home.index', {
  url: '',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  controller: 'HomeController',
  data: {
    ignoreState: true
  },
  templateUrl: 'players/home.client.view.html',
  resolve: {
    reward_data: function($http, $stateParams) {
      return $http.get('/api/v1/rewards');
    },
    answers_data: function($http, $stateParams){
      return $http.get('/api/v1/answers/current');
    }
  }
})
.state('home.game', {
  url: 'game',
  controller: 'GameController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  data: {
    roles: ['player']
  },
  templateUrl: 'players/game/game.client.view.html'
});
}]);
```

And I put alert() in top of controller file is working and inside controller function is not working, I thought is not working since route can't detect the path

Any Sugesstion?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found actually problem, A real problem. if some state have resolve function it will be freeze ui. I don't know why because I never met before. I working with resolve many time only error form server will make resolve and ui will freeze. I ran "rails s -e production" is work normal but on real server not working